# Remove multiple deleted variables from .txt file

Tags: perl, batch-file

I am trying to delete "Removed variables" from a text file.
To remove data which starts as "# Begin Removed Variable" and ends at "# End Removed Variable".

The pattern is as below :

```
# Begin Test Case

  File = ..\SVN\XXX.CPP
  Procedure = XX
  Procedure Number = 1
  Member Of = 1
  Creation Date = Jun XX 2019 14:36:44
  Description = This test is to verify 

    # Begin Variable

      Name = YY
      Decl_type = uchar*
      Usage = N
      TBrun Analysis = Compare
      Value = YY

    # End Variable

    # Begin Removed Variable

      Name = b_side_fired
      Decl_type = gun_class
      Usage = M

    # End Removed Variable

# End Test Case
```

I am new to it, so i am unable to judge and proceed.

The output is as stated below. Remove all "# Begin Removed variables....its contents beneath and end at "End Removed variables" and all its occurances in file.
For ex: as per below all removed variables are removed.

```
# Begin Test Case

  File = ..\SVN\XXX.CPP
  Procedure = XX
  Procedure Number = 1
  Member Of = 1
  Creation Date = Jun XX 2019 14:36:44
  Description = This test is to verify 

    # Begin Variable

      Name = YY
      Decl_type = uchar*
      Usage = N
      TBrun Analysis = Compare
      Value = YY

    # End Variable
# End Test Case
```

Comment: How is this related to [tag:batch-file]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be done:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'config.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

my $start = q[# Begin Removed Variable];
my $end = q[# End Removed Variable];

$str =~ s/^\s*\Q$start\E.*?\Q$end\E.*?$//gems;

print $str;
```

### Update

To overwrite the existing file:

```
open ( my $save_fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
print $save_fh $str;
close $save_fh;
```

A safer approach might be not to modify the script, but instead redirect its output to another file, for example:

```
$ perl script.pl > config_new.txt
```

In this way, the original `config.txt` becomes a backup file.

Comment: Hi Hakon, get below errors: 
>my $str = do { local $/; ; 0<$fh 1>} The system cannot find the file specified.
>close $fh 'close' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
>my $start = q[# Begin Removed Variable];
'my' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
>my $end = q[# End Removed Variable];
'my' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
>$str =~ s/\s*\Q$start\E.*?\Q$end\E.*?$//gems;
'$str' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Kumar Hi! You can run the script from the terminal using `perl script.pl` (if you have saved the script first with the name `script.pl`)

Comment: Thanks Hakon. It works...but the output is available in cmd window but not replaced in that text file. What command i need to add in so that output of Conif.txt....is replaced in COnfig.txt after processing.

Comment: @Kumar You are welcome. See my updated answer.

Comment: If i update using above update i get compilation errors. I replaced original code  with ur update.                           open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;                                                                                         And if put code  to copy the contents into new file as suggested i get below error open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

Comment: @Kumar Can you send me the code? (My email is in my profile).

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner that edits the file in-place:

```
 perl -ni -e 'print unless /# Begin Removed Variable/ .. /# End Removed Variable/' yourfile.txt
```

Basically, it just prints lines unless they're in one of those removed blocks. [More information](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Range-Operators) on the use of scalar `..`.

Non-inplace awk version for comparision (`,` is like `..` in perl):

```
 awk '/# Begin Removed Variable/, /# End Removed Variable/ { next } 1' yourfile.txt
```

and sed:

```
sed '/# Begin Removed Variable/, /# End Removed Variable/ d' yourfile.txt
```

Some versions of sed support `-i` for inplace editing like perl.